# c# TextchangedEventHandler does not work the same in WM10 as WP7

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-mobile

At the moment I am working on a porting case for changing my app from WP7 Silerlight to Windows 10 mobile UAP platform.

In my old application I added listeners to textboxes in the following way :

```
 private void AddListeners(Listeners type) {
        switch (type) {
            case Listeners.All:
                txtCity.TextChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(txtCity_TextChanged);
```

Now I know that System.windows.controle changed to Windows.UI.XAML.Control but it seems that the textChangedEventHandler has changed. When I change the code to :

```
txtStreet.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(txtStreet_TextChanged);
```

The error :

> No overload for 'txtCity_Textchanged' matches delegate TextChangedEvent Handler

Now I know that TextchangedEventHandler requires an Object Sender and TextChangedEventArgs e

but when I add an ExtchangedEventHandler it gives the following error:

> TextChangedEventHandler is a type which is not valid in the given context

It might be an simple error but for some reason I am net seeing why this gives the following error.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: can you show the `txtStreet_TextChanged` method declaration

Comment: Shreesha you are the winner of the day! For some dumb reason i forgot to check this and there where 2 errors there!

Thank you!!

Comment: problem is you can not select comment as answer:)

Comment: How can I do this ? Kinda new to stackoverflow and I do not know how to do this with a comment! Sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## shreesa provided the answer:

It was in the method of txtStreet_Textchanged and was kind of a dumb error of mine.